# Pressing UIBarButtonItem on a NavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I've added a button the my navigation bar like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(methodtocall:)];          

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
[anotherButton release];
```

However when I press this I get a InvalidArgumentException. This is in a brand new navigation project. Does anyone know why I get this behaviour?

Comment: Can we see your action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your action method like this:

```
-(void) methodtocall:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender {
   //do stuff...
}
```

You are probably getting an `InvalidArgument` error because you didn't define your method to receive the `UIBarButtonItem`.